# Referencing inner types of templated types in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to create a templated class with a template parameter `X` that refers to a class or typedef defined within `X`. This snippet of code:

```
template <class X>
struct C {
    void Method(X::Child c);
};
```

Doesn't compile, because:

```
test.cc:3:20: error: ‘X::Child’ is not a type
     void Method(X::Child c);
                    ^~~~~
```

My understanding of SFINAE was that exactly this was allowed; I would expect that sort of error when the template was instantiated with a type `X` that doesn't have an inner type named `Child`, but here I get the error without instantiating the template at all.

Comment: `void Method(typename X::Child c);`.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42!